# in Dropzone.js Is it possible to grab the base64 encoded preview thumbnail data from within the "accept" function?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

i see that the base64 data does live inside the accept(file) object but i am wondering if there is an easy helper to just grab this data in JS so i can build my own preview UX.

Comment: why is this getting downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to either pick the preview src data out of the accept(file) object nor was i able to use any combination of jquery selectors with attr or prop to pull the src out. The only way i could do anything with the preview image was to directly clone it and then pin it to another element on the page.

Not sure it matters this was running as JS on a blaze template.

```
let previewThumb=file.previewElement.querySelector("img");
```